# Where is the Windows XP SUA ksh default .profile file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ksh, sua

How can I figure out where the Windows XP SUA ksh .profile file is on a system where I was not the person who installed it? (I'm searching google for the answer, but the combinations of ksh, windows XP, and profile lead to many, many hits that I am still digging through.) It is NOT in my user directory, so it is probably the system default .profile that I need to find?

Problem, if it has any bearing: The path is radically different before and after I start the ksh, and after the ksh starts it includes some contextually bad paths.

All I really want is to keep the path set up in the cmd.com batch environment from before ksh is invoked, but I think I first need to figure out where the change is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is apparently located at C:\Windows\SUA\etc\profile

Answer (score 0):

Open the run dialog by hitting Windows-Key+R and type the following command followed by return:

```
explorer "%USERPROFILE%"
```

A Windows explorer window should appear showing the content of the current user profile folder. The file you are looking for may be there or in some subdir, especially inside `ApplicationData` or `Local Settings\ApplicationData` (note: I work on an Italian XP version and dir names are localized, thus I may have spelled them incorrectly).

Note that you may have to enable the visualization of hidden files, if that `.profile` file was saved with the hidden attribute set.

Otherwise you may also search in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users`, which is the folder where all settings common to all the users are stored.